# Need help with relative path from application page to sitepage

Tags: application-pages, relative-path

I am currently developing a SharePoint visual web part farm solution. I'm having trouble determining how without hardcoding a link to get from http://sharetest/sites/Dev/_layouts/15/HelpDesk/EditWorkOrder.aspx?2
to http://sharetest/sites/Dev/SitePages/Tickets.aspx. I shouldn't have to type in /sites/dev as when I move it to the live SharePoint it will be wrong.

I have tried many variations and can't seem to find one that works.

//Response.Redirect("http://sharetest/sites/Dev/SitePages/Tickets.aspx");
  Response.Redirect("~/SitePages/Tickets.aspx");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get web absolute url and concatenate it with "/SitePages/Tickets.aspx".

On **Client** side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var YOUR_URL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/SitePages/Tickets.aspx";
Response.Redirect(YOUR_URL);
</script>
```

On **Server** side:

```
SPWeb curWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
string YOUR_URL = curWeb.Url + "/SitePages/Tickets.aspx";
Response.Redirect(YOUR_URL);
```

Comment: Also you can try to use ~site token
`Response.Redirect("~site/SitePages/Tickets.aspx");`


[URLs and Tokens in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/urls-and-tokens-in-sharepoint)